# Magento 2: Shipment Email gives Missing required argument $debugHintsPath

Tags: magento2, email, shipment

I'm sending shipment using below code

**magento\vendor\magento\module-shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save.php**

```
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Missing required argument $debugHintsPath of Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Plugin\DebugHints.' in D:\wamp\www\
magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\
Develop...', Array, Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Develop...')
#2 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList.php(233): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Develop...')
#3 D:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(151): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Magento\\Framewo...', 'd in D:\wamp\
www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 45
```

Withing Magento I'm not getting any issue. I'm making my custom script in only that I'm getting this error.

Answer (score -2):

According to the code you shared, it seems that you have syntax error, it should be: 
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);

Comment: It's typo mistake